# How to select the last review for each item using LINQ-To-Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am a new user of LINQ and I am developing a simple shopping system. I am trying now to write a LINQ statement that will retrieve the last review (based on the Review Date) for each item in the database. I am using Linq-To-Entities using Entity Framework 4. And I have the following tables:

```
Items Table: ID, Name,
UserReviews Table:  ID, Description, ReviewDate,  ItemID
```

I came up with the following LINQ statement, but it showed me all the reviews for each item instead of showing the last review for each item:

```
var query = from item in context.Items
            from review in context.UserReviews                                          
            where item.ID == review.ItemID
           && (review.ReviewDate >= fromDate.Date && review.ReviewDate <= toDate)
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              Name = item.Name,
                                              Review = review.Description,
                                              Date = review.ReviewDate
                                          };
```

Snapshot of the desired results:
[image]

**Could you please tell me how to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

You could get the most recent review by using the `.Max` function on the query:

```
var lastReview = query.Max(x => x.Date);
```